# Linphone opus codec sampling rate

Tags: sip, voip, linphone, opus, linphone-sdk

I would like to use opus codec in linphone

But I have a few problems using it. If someone with opus codec knowledge could help me out would appreciate it.
How I can force audio sampling scheme to 8000 Hz? Currently, it uses 48000 Hz only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Opus is negotiated in sdp using "opus/48000": but it can be configured to encode at 8000, 16000, 32000 and 48000. May be you are mixing sdp frequency for timestamp and the real samplerate/quality used by the encoder!

Comment: So, you mean "opus/48000" in SDP doesn't mean a 48000 Hz sampling rate? For example, GSM is an 8000 Hz sampling rate coded with about 24 Kbps upload data. But When I use Opus (48000) in linphone I have 50 Kbps upload data. I want to use Opus 8000 in order to lower data usage.

Comment: Yes: opus/48000 in sdp doesn't mean 48kHz in samplerate. See rfc7587 and rfc6716 (for example section 2.1.1.  Bitrate). The code and sdp options will match settings of libopus to use lower bitrates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [rfc7587 Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7587), you can read this:

```
Opus supports 5 different audio bandwidths, which can be adjusted
during a stream.  The RTP timestamp is incremented with a 48000 Hz
clock rate for all modes of Opus and all sampling rates.  The unit
for the timestamp is samples per single (mono) channel.  The RTP
timestamp corresponds to the sample time of the first encoded sample
in the encoded frame.  For data encoded with sampling rates other
than 48000 Hz, the sampling rate has to be adjusted to 48000 Hz.
```

Reading more in the rfc7587, you will find out that, in SDP, you will always see the codec being using "OPUS/48000/2", no matter the real sampling rates.

No matter the real sampling rate, as explained above, the RTP timestamp will always be incremented with a 48000 Hz clock rate.

If you wish to control the real sampling rate for the codec (and thus, the bandwidth), you can use the following SDP parameters: **maxplaybackrate** and **maxaveragebitrate** are the ones to be used.

Section 3.1.1 is listing the relation between **maxaveragebitrate** and the sampling rate:

```
3.1.1.  Recommended Bitrate

   For a frame size of 20 ms, these are the bitrate "sweet spots" for  Opus in various configurations:

   o  8-12 kbit/s for NB speech,
   o  16-20 kbit/s for WB speech,
   o  28-40 kbit/s for FB speech,
   o  48-64 kbit/s for FB mono music, and
   o  64-128 kbit/s for FB stereo music.
```

Conclusion: to use only 8000Hz in OPUS, you must negotiate with such parameters, where 12kbit/s is the maximum setup for opus in NB speech:

```
   m=audio 54312 RTP/AVP 101
   a=rtpmap:101 opus/48000/2
   a=fmtp:101 maxplaybackrate=8000; sprop-maxcapturerate=8000; maxaveragebitrate=12000
```

I don't know if linphone is following all the parameters, but this is the theory!